# Lorentz structure of coupling in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

what is meant by the "Lorentz structure of the coupling in QED" as a possible test for QED?

Comment: I think some references and/or background material is probably necessary (e.g., it looks like you are quoting something, if so, what is it?).

Comment: well I'm quoting my professors slides. He's listing possible tests for QED. One is for example "energy dependence of the coupling (running)". And another is the above...

Comment: Your teacher probably invented this term. I am sure that it means something, I just don't know what. You should try asking him about this.

Comment: And it would be even better if you post an answer to your own question here after asking your teacher about this.

Comment: He may meaned that the only way to introduce lorentz covariant interaction between 4-potential $A_{\mu}$ (which relates to massless particles) with the matter is such in which charge is conserved.